intercept and modify packets sent and received on port 2106 when connections are established via random ports
I am trying to intercept and modify packets that are sent and received on port 2106, but the connections are established using random ports. As a result, I don't know which localhost port to use to create a proxy to accomplish this.
With the following code, I can intercept and read the packets:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sync"

    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
)

func capturePackets(device string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    handle, err := pcap.OpenLive(device, 65536, true, pcap.BlockForever)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error opening interface %s: %v", device, err)
        return
    }
    defer handle.Close()

    var filter = "tcp and (dst port 2106 or src port 2106)"
    err = handle.SetBPFFilter(filter)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error setting filter for %s: %v", device, err)
        return
    }

    packetSource := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType())
    for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {
        fmt.Printf("Captured packet on interface %s: %v\n", device, packet)
    }
}

func main() {
    devices, err := pcap.FindAllDevs()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, device := range devices {
        wg.Add(1)
        go capturePackets(device.Name, &wg) // Capture packets in a goroutine
    }

    // Wait for all goroutines to finish
    wg.Wait()
}

However, I also need to send a new packet based on the intercepted one, meaning I need to intercept and send another packet to the server depending on the packet I receive. Could someone help me figure out how to do this?
I understand that with iptables, I could redirect all traffic intended for the server to my proxy server, but I want to achieve everything within a single Go binary. Is this possible?

This is a sketch and was not tested, but i hope it gives the general idea.
It uses the raw data of the packetSource.Packages() -> package.Data() as an io.Reader which can then be copied to several writers using an io.MultiWriter (a io.TeeWriter would be sufficient for only two, but this is more extendable).
So from performance side, this might be a good starting point. If the focus is more on doing extensive inspections using the gopackets Layers, then i would assume, using channels for the inspection and a single reader + writer would be better.
package main
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
)
func capturePackets(device string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    handle, err := pcap.OpenLive(device, 65536, true, pcap.BlockForever)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error opening interface %s: %v", device, err)
        return
    }
    defer handle.Close()
    var filter = "tcp and (dst port 2106 or src port 2106)"
    err = handle.SetBPFFilter(filter)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error setting filter for %s: %v", device, err)
        return
    }
    // the ioutil.Discard must be replaced by an io.Writer to do the actual work
    analyticsWriter := io.Discard
    forwardingWriter := io.Discard
    // this will copy to both at the sane time, reducing memory usage
    multiWriter := io.MultiWriter(analyticsWriter, forwardingWriter)
    // here the logic should wire both writers, so the results of the analyticsWriter
    // can also be sent to forwardingWriter (if that is the desired architecture...)
    startAnalytics(analyticsWriter, forwardingWriter)
    packetSource := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType())
    for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {
        bytesWritten, err := io.Copy(multiWriter, bytes.NewReader(packet.Data()))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("warn: could not copy: %s", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Captured packet on interface %s, %d bytes written: %v\n", device, bytesWritten, packet)
    }
}
func startAnalytics(_, _ io.Writer) {
    // analyse and use forwarding writer
}
func main() {
    devices, err := pcap.FindAllDevs()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, device := range devices {
        wg.Add(1)
        go capturePackets(device.Name, &wg) // Capture packets in a goroutine
    }
    // Wait for all goroutines to finish
    wg.Wait()
}

